# How to customize vrapper block indentation?

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin

I know it is possible to increase or decrease indentation of a block using n>> like in Vim. This used to work on Vrapper in my environment until recently, but now it is no longer smart, converting tabs to spaces, and not respecting my default tab width.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin, and making .vrapperrc look similar to my .vimrc. Neither attempts made any difference.

Comment: A possible regression? You should try vrapper's issue tracker.

Answer (score 7):

A friend helped out with a suggestion that worked. It had nothing to do with smartindent, or shiftwidth. Apparently `:set expandtab` is the default setting. Using `:set noexpandtab` took care of this for me.

(I use tabs, not spaces, let us not do that war. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have found similar behaviour with vrapper. As @romainl suggested, I took a look at the issue tracker [and found this issue](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues/273).

Using set sw=4 resolved my indenting issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Eclipse + pydev + vrapper,  set sw=4 is the perfect solution to the problem. And tabs is not recommended by python.

Comment: It is a shame that Vwrapper has its own settings. It would be great if they had managed instead to use the default eclipse settings from "Code Style" for the current language :-(

Comment: Also this appears to work only for one editor window at at time currently. I tried `setg` but does nothing.